# How to give new line to values in My response JSON output in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, backend

I am creating a instagram **scraper** using nodeJs. I am **scraping** links in JSOn format and showing it in page but all the link are getting in one line. I have to differentiate different values in different line in JSON. I have tried JSON.stringify and JSON.parse but its not working any solution

Output coming : `{"title":"Astronomy (@astronomyforum) posted on Instagram: “An interesting question to think about is what would happen if the moon exploded?   Imagine the moon exploding and what that would look…” • Jul 26, 2021 at 6:36pm UTC","url":"https://www.instagram.com/p/CRzPjbRqxim/","file":"video","video_link":"https://instagram.fdel2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/225510060_149101203965285_678675776161943659_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fdel2-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=66WeoAC3o4gAX9Oh7VW&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=610E2F5C&oh=efc2bc202dd59cb4a08744321c26f1f9&_nc_sid=83d603"}`

Output I want:

```
{
   "title":"Astronomy (@astronomyforum) posted on Instagram: “An interesting question to think about is what would happen if the moon exploded?   Imagine the moon exploding and what that would look…” • Jul 26, 2021 at 6:36pm UTC",
   "url":"https://www.instagram.com/p/CRzPjbRqxim/",
   "file":"video",
   "video_link":"https://instagram.fdel2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/225510060_149101203965285_678675776161943659_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fdel2-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=66WeoAC3o4gAX9Oh7VW&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=610E2F5C&oh=efc2bc202dd59cb4a08744321c26f1f9&_nc_sid=83d603"
}
```

Here's My code:

```
             let video_link = $('meta[property="og:video"]').attr('content');
             let file = $('meta[property="og:type"]').attr('content');
             let url = $('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content');
             let title = $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content');

             res.status(200).json({ title, url, file, video_link});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the third parameter in `JSON.stringify`

like this:

```
let json = { uno: 1, dos: 2 };
let newlineJson = JSON.stringify(json, null, '\t');
```

then `newlineJson` would be:

```
{
    "uno": 1,
    "dos": 2
}
```

And then combine it with a `pre` tag so the browser will display it accordingly

```
res.status(200).send(`<pre>${JSON.stringify({ title, url, file, video_link}, null, 2)</pre>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about browser you must add any extention for Json Viewer .For example this is for chrome ;

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh?hl=en